# Default Set Empty value for jqxDataTime Input

Tags: jqxwidgets

We need help for Date Time Input to set by default blank. We are using the code below for that, but we can’t set it blank.

```
$("#start_date1").jqxDateTimeInput({width: 150, height: 22, formatString:'dd-MMM-yy', theme: theme,clearString: 'Clear'});
```

Could you please help us?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, just set the value property to null, e.g.:

```
   $("#jqxWidget").jqxDateTimeInput({ width: '250px', height: '25px', value: null });
```

The clearString property refers to the “Clear” button in the dropdown calendar.